# How to define DRUPAL_WEIGHT_SELECT_MAX?

Tags: drupal-7

I have a website powered by drupal, this morning I encountered the following error when i tried to view the block setting. 
Notice: Use of undefined constant DRUPAL_WEIGHT_SELECT_MAX - assumed 'DRUPAL_WEIGHT_SELECT_MAX' in form_process_weight() (line 3801 of /home/project-web/career/htdocs/includes/form.inc).

How to address this problem ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[`DRUPAL_WEIGHT_SELECT_MAX`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/constant/DRUPAL_WEIGHT_SELECT_MAX/7) is defined in the `system.module` file. If it's undefined I'd check the integrity of your core Drupal files as it might indicate a bit of a problem.

Just for info it's defined as such:

```
define('DRUPAL_WEIGHT_SELECT_MAX', 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, it's very helpful.